# Can't compile servlet file.

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

I was testing a demo servlet file But, the servlet doesn't seem to respond. I'm not able to understand the problem.

When I click submit on the HTML form the URL is 
    localhost:8080/Beer-V1/SelectBeer.do

But, shouldn't it be /BeerSelect? Because of @WebServlet("/BeerSelect") ???

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-   app_2_5.xsd" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" metadata-complete="false" 
version="3.0">

 <servlet>
<servlet-name>CH3 Beer</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CH3 Beer</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**BeerSelect.java**

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/BeerSelect")
public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public BeerSelect() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");

    String c = request.getParameter("color");
    out.println("<br> Got Beer Color " + c);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click submit on the HTML form the URL is localhost:8080/Beer-V1/SelectBeer.do
>
> But, shouldn't it be /BeerSelect? Because of @WebServlet("/BeerSelect") ???

1. web-container associates a "context-path" for each of the web-application deployed and in your case, I believe it is "Beer-V1".
2. You have overridden the mapping in web.xml as below and hence you are seeing *.do

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>CH3 Beer</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

The xml DD overrides the annotations.

Comment: So do I change /SelectBeer.do to BeerSelect? and also keep the @WebServlet("/BeerSelect") ?

Comment: @RonyJohn Remove the web.xml and use annotations or the otherway round

Comment: Okay, do I make any changes in here? <form method="POST" action="BeerSelect">. I'm removed the web.xml and kept the annotations.